# jsTree get_json function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I have a jstree tree that I'm trying to extract the structure of using get_json (in order to post it back to the server), but I don't seem to be getting any tree info in the returned object.

The tree is setup and working properly in

```
$("#site-structure-container").jstree({plugins : ["themes", "json_data"]});
```

(excluded above is the json I've supplied (from the first demo [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)) to setup the tree) and I'm using

```
data = $("#site-structure-container").jstree("get_json", -1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

to check whats extracted.  This is what is shown in the log:

```
{"length":1,"0":{"jQuery16203561271743551655":3},"context":{"jQuery16203561271743551655":1},"selector":"#site-structure-container"}
```

Surely I should be getting the tree structure in here?  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Have eventually tracked it down to jQuery version..  1.6.2 (which I was using) doesn't appear to work in the same way that 1.4 to 1.6.1 do.  Changing to any 1.4 to 1.6.1 means I get the result I expected ie.:

```
[{"data":{"attr":{},"title":"A node","icon":"checkbox"},"attr":{"id"...
```

I don't know exactly what is going wrong with 1.6.2+, but I've found it doesn't make any difference whether I use `.jstree("get_json")` or `.jstree("blahblah")` or `.jstree()`, I always get the same unexpected output as above (`{"length":1...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have eventually tracked it down to jQuery version.. 1.6.2 (which I was using) doesn't appear to work in the same way that 1.4 to 1.6.1 do. Changing to any 1.4 to 1.6.1 means I get the result I expected ie.:

`[{"data":{"attr":{},"title":"A node","icon":"checkbox"},"attr":{"id"...`

I don't know exactly what is going wrong with 1.6.2, but I've found it doesn't make any difference whether I use `.jstree("get_json")` or `.jstree("blahblah")` or `.jstree()`, I always get the same unexpected output as above ({"length":1...).

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following url,

http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/jquery-tree-using-json-as-dataset/

**UPDATE**:

Use the following code you can declare an alternate variable for $,

```
          var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then use $j for jQuery, instead of $.

If this is the conflict issue the above will solve it. Normally conflicts occur if an external library is used other than Jquery library.

**note:** be sure to **include jQuery1.6.2.js after the other library**, so it knows what to give $ back to.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: This is using JSON as data source but isn't using get_json anywhere?

Comment: I've just tried adding `ui` and `checkbox`, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Solved now - see Update above.

Comment: @Chris Anstey,So by replacing latest Jquery with any of the previous versions worked for you with the same code.This behavior may be because of some conflicts between the "jquery.jstree.js" and the "Jquery1.6.2.js".Both might be using $ symbol in their definitions.If any such definition is common in both with the $ symbol it will definitely results in a conflict.As a result of this conflict you may not get the expected result.Try replacing the $ symbol with any other (otherwise use the word jquery as such) in our code.See my answer update section above.

Comment: It looks like there is a wider issue with 1.6.2 (see [here](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/42) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/07420566452622f37b01e69bbbdcbeeb5317e065)), so I'll stick with 1.6.1 for now.